# What are my prospects of recovering old version of file on BTRFS

Tags: data-recovery, btrfs

I've accidentally overwritten an important file on BTRFS.

Knowing that this filesystem is COW, it should be in theory possible to recover an old version of the file.

Unfortunately googling didn't reveal relevant information. Can someone please advice me, what steps can I do (if any)?

Comment: I guess, the answer is: "grim"...

Answer (score 3):

You should try the btrfs-undelete tool posted on this mailing list thread by Jörg Walter.

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.btrfs/22560